# Prove that given distribution is a binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, proof-explanation, binomial-distribution

I'm taking an elementary probability course and came across this problem. I know what a binomial distribution is and its properties. But I have no idea how to prove if a given distribution is one.

Given distribution:

[image]

Just saying that the given distribution has discrete values and we only have 2 states ("success" and "fail") is enough?

PS: I'm not a native speaker, so if anything was cloudy, I can clarify them.

Comment: this is not clear.  All the table tells us is that there is some random variable $X$ which can take the values $\{0,1,2,3\}$, and we are told the probabilities of each.  What is it you are asking about the variable $X$?

Comment: It it was a binomial distribution, $n$ must be $3$ and $p=\sqrt[3]{0.064}$.

Comment: The problem just asks to prove that this is a binomial distribution. No other information was given. So I'm really confused right now..

Comment: Is it even possible to "prove" anything? This is one of 30 problems of my midterm assignment. Should I just write "insufficient information thus impossible to prove anything"? It could be the correct answer. But then again I don't really know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove that using the moment generating function (MGF). Note that if $X\sim$ Binomial$(n,p)$, the MGF of $X$ is $(pe^t+1-p)^n$. In your problem, based on the probability distribution, the MGF of the random variable is $0.064+0.288e^t+0.432e^{2t}+0.216e^{3t}=(0.6e^t+0.4)^3$, so indeed, this is a binomial distribution with $n=3$ and $p=0.6$.